# How to do a multiplication of two different columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas

How can I make this account that I made in excel in python...

I wanted to take the column "Acumulado" and multiply by the bottom row of the column 'Selic por diy' and add that value in that row, and so do the same thing successively

```
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data":['06/03/2006','07/03/2006','08/03/2006','09/03/2006','10/03/2006','13/03/2006','14/03/2006','15/03/2006','16/03/2006','17/03/2006'],
                   "Taxa SELIC":[17.29,17.29,17.29,16.54,16.54,16.54,16.54,16.54,16.54,16.54,]})

df['Taxa Selic %'] = df['Taxa SELIC'] / 100
df['Selic por dia'] = (1 + df['Taxa SELIC'])**(1/252)
```

Data frame Example
[image]

Here's an example I did in excel

[image]

Second example of how I would like it to look
[image]

Comment: Please, show some python/pandas code snippet and what you tried so far.

Comment: Does this work? `df['Selic por dia'].cumprod()`

Answer (score 0):

Not an efficient method, but you can try this:

```
import numpy as np
selic_per_dia = list(df['Selic por dia'].values)
accumulado = [1000000*selic_per_dia[0]]
for i,value in enumerate(selic_per_dia):
    if i==0:
        continue
    else:
        accumulado.append(accumulado[i-1]*value)
df['Acumulado'] = accumulado
df.loc[-1] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1000000]  
df.index = df.index + 1  
df = df.sort_index()
```